# PostgreSQL - Passing Array to Stored Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have two separate databases (MySQL and PostgreSQL) that maintain different data-sets from different departments in my organization-- this can't be changed. I need to connect to one to get a list of `symbols` or `ids` from the first DB with a DBAPI in python and request the other set and operate on it.

(I've spent a lot of time on this approach, and it makes sense because of other components in my architecture, so unless there is a *much better* alternative, I'd like to stick with this method.)

```
CREATE TABLE foo (fooid int, foosubid int, fooname text);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 1, 'Joe');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 2, 'Ed');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 1, 'Mary');

CREATE FUNCTION get_results(text[]) RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
SELECT fooname, fooid, foosubid FROM foo WHERE name IN $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

In reality my SQL is much more complicated, but I think this method completely describes the purpose. **Can I pass in an arbitrary length parameter into a stored procedure or user defined function and return a result set?**

I would like to call the function like:

```
SELECT * FROM get_results(('Joe', 'Ed'));
SELECT * FROM get_results(('Joe', 'Mary'));
SELECT * FROM get_results(('Ed'));
```

I believe using the `IN` and passing these parameters (if it's possible) would give me the same (or comparable) performance as a `JOIN`. For my current use case the symbols won't exceed 750-1000 'names', but if performance is an issue here I'd like to know why, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RETURNS TABLE` instead of `RETURNS SETOF record`. This will simplify the function calls.

You cannot use `IN` operator in that way. Use `ANY` instead.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_results(text[]) 
RETURNS TABLE (fooname text, fooid int, foosubid int) 
AS $$
    SELECT fooname, fooid, foosubid 
    FROM foo 
    WHERE fooname = ANY($1);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM get_results(ARRAY['Joe']);

 fooname | fooid | foosubid 
---------+-------+----------
 Joe     |     1 |        1
(1 row)
```

---

If the function returns setof records you have to put a column definition list in every function call:

```
SELECT * 
FROM get_results(ARRAY['Joe']) AS (fooname text, fooid int, foosubid int)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Row vs Array constructor

`('Joe', 'Ed')` is equivalent to `ROW('Joe', 'Ed')` and creates a new row.

But your function accepts an array. To create one, call it with an Array constructor:

```
SELECT * FROM get_results(ARRAY['Joe', 'Ed']);
```

### Variadic functions

You can declare your input parameter as `VARIADIC` like so

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_results(VARIADIC text[]) RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
SELECT fooname, fooid, foosubid FROM foo WHERE name = ANY($1);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

It accepts a variable number of arguments. You can call it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM get_results('Joe', 'Ed');
```

More on functions with variable length arguments: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-sql.html

Answer (score 1):

Jared,
If you want just to pass an array into a procedure or function call in where clause, you can try using this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_results(text[]) RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
SELECT fooname, fooid, foosubid FROM foo WHERE name = any($1);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```